# Online POSTGRESQL database error "undefined symbol: GEOSFrechetDistanceDensify"

Tags: postgis, postgresql, qgis-3, mac

Using QGIS 3 on mac book air and set up a POSTGRESQL database with Acugis 6 days ago. Everything's been working fine and no issues. The yesterday everything went off and was unable to see the layers on POSTGIS window. Lets me connect and login to the schema but I've been getting the error below.

```
ERROR: could not load library "/usr/pgsql-11/lib/postgis-2.5.so": /usr/pgsql-11/lib/postgis-2.5.so: undefined symbol: GEOSFrechetDistanceDensify
SQL state: XX000
```

I've researched it but am unable to find a resolution on how this could be fixed.

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar issue on Centos 7 with PG 11 and Postgis 2.5 while dump/updating the database.

In my case 'yum remove geos36' solved it.

Hope this helps or at least give you an in sight!

M.